# What is included in main memory access time?

Tags: memory-management, time, operating-system, paging

If main memory access time is say, 100ns. What does that actually mean ?
Consider a system with no TLB and not page faults occuring in pagetables. 
If we consider 1 level paging, will the access time be 100? or 200 ? (page table(1 memory access time) + data(2nd memory access time).
Same is my question with 2 level paging.
In all, what lies inside this time? Is it going to the page table, searching an entry within it and reading one of its entry ? This idea confuses me especially in multilevel paging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That means that from the time an *agent* presents an address  to *the memory circuitry* until the time that the data can be captured by the *agent*, 100ns has elapsed.

With a flat page table, and no caching the best you could hope for is 200ns.  Realistically, it takes time to read the address out of the page table entry, so you might miss a clock on the second memory op.  If the clock is say 1/4 access time, it might take you 225ns to read with this.

An n-level one never searches; it knows from the virtual address precisely how to walk the page tables; but as in the flat page table above, there may be some latency at each read, so reading a memory location with an n-level page table would require (n * 100 + n * clock-latency) + 100.

A memory read operation looks something like this:

```
Clock  _______________|----------|__________|----------|__________
AddressValid _______/--------------\________
Address ..........AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA]........
DataValid   _______________________________/-------------\________
Data    .................................DDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDDD.......
```

So, the points to take away are:  The signal lines are only sampled on a clock edge (rising or falling).  The Address is made available slightly before the AddressValid signal is set; and the AddressValid signal is set slightly before the clock rises.  This ensures that the Address and signal have time to become stable before they are sampled.

When the clock falls, the AddressValid signal is removed.

The memory device, on the rising clock edge, detects AddressValid, so samples the Address value.  It grabs the memory, makes it available, then just before the rising clock edge, sets the DataValid signal.

When the clock falls, the memory device removes the DataValid signal.

On the rising clock edge, the *agent* detects DataValid, so samples the Data value.  The read operation is now complete.

Note that this is the operation of a memory circuit circa 1976.  Modern ones are much more fancy, but essentially the same.